# Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL - LogStashLogger not connecting to Logstash - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, logstash

I've been fighting on getting the logs to work on a Dockerized Rails 5.1.5 application with the ELK (Elasticsearch Logstash Kibana) stack (which is Dockerized as well). I've been having problems on setting it up. I haven't been able to send a single log to logstash from Rails.

The current problem is:

> ERROR -- : [LogStashLogger::Device::TCP] Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL - Cannot
>   assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 5228

At first, I thought there was a problem with my current ELK configuration. After days spent, I finally figured out that ELK was working correctly by sending a dummy .log file through the `nc` command using Ubuntu for Win10, and it worked  !!!

Now that I know the problem is with Rails, I've been trying a different set of combinations, but I still haven't gotten it to work:

1. I checked that the configuration from Logstash is correctly accepting TCP, and is the right port.
2. Changed to a different port, both in Logstash and Rails.
3. I'm currently using **Docker-Compose V3**. I initialized ELK first, and then Rails (but the problem still creeped in)
4. Switched between UDP and TCP.
5. Did not specified a codec in the logstash.conf.
6. Specified the json_lines codec in the logstash.conf
7. I've tried specifying a `link` between logstash and rails in docker-compose.yml (Even though it's deprecated for docker-compose v3)
8. I've tried bringing them together through a `network`in docker-compose.
9. I've tried specifying a `depends_on` logstash in the rails app in docker-compose.

I'm running out of ideas:

Here's the logging config (Right now it's in development.rb):

```
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Logstash.new
  config.logger = LogStashLogger.new(type: :tcp, host: 'localhost', port: 5228)
```

The logstash conf:

```
input {
 tcp {
    port => 5228
    codec => json_lines
  }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    }
}
```

And last, but not least, here's the Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    # This specifies a MySQL image that will be created with root privileges 
    # Note that MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD is Mandatory!
    # We specify the 5.7.21'th version of MySQL from the docker repository.
    # We are using mariadb because there's an apparent problem with permissions. 
    # See: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69
    image: mariadb:10.3.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootPassword"
      MYSQL_USER: "ruby"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "userPassword"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "dev"
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
      - ./db/rails_.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/rails_.sql
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elk
  logstash:
    container_name: logstash
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.2.3
    volumes:
      - ./elk/logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      - ./elk/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
    command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
      - "5228:5228"
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.3
    volumes:
      - ./elk/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      LOGSTASH_HOST: localhost
      SECRET_MYSQL_HOST: 'db'
      SECRET_MYSQL_DATABASE: 'dev'
      SECRET_MYSQL_USERNAME: 'ruby'
      SECRET_MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'userPassword'
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3001 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    links:
      - db
      - logstash
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/rails"
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    expose:
      - "3001"
    networks:
      - elk
  db-data:
    driver: local
  elasticsearch:
    driver: local

networks:
    elk:
      driver: bridge
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name.

According to the `docker-compose.yaml` file, `logstash` container is accessible on `logstash:5228` from other containers, so logging config on `app` container should be changed to:

```
config.log_level = :debug
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Logstash.new
  config.logger = LogStashLogger.new(type: :tcp, host: 'logstash', port: 5228, formatter: :json_lines, sync: true))
```

Check that logstash.conf is like this:

```
input {
 tcp {
    port => 5228
    codec => json_lines
  }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! That was... *part of the problem*!!! Thank you! Fortunately I found out this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/dezmodue/ruby-logger/. Surprisingly, it was working with the same credentials you provided to me. I digged into the image and found out that LogStashLogger has the formatter parameter! Adding it PLUS the host as 'logstash' did the trick! I apologize taking the opportunity to edit your answer to add those few tidbits, as I wanted to give you the "right one"

Comment: One more thing, for anyone who sees this, if you're using docker-compose it will throw an error at the beginning while the Elasticsearch and Logstash images start to boot up. Wait for them to get connected and LogstashLogger will be up and running.